# Do I need to quit my node redis client instance using .quit()?

Tags: node.js, redis

Looking at this code below (taken from the [git page](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis))

```
var redis  = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient(), multi;

// runs immediately
client.mset("incr thing", 100, "incr other thing", 1, redis.print);
multi = client.multi();

// drains multi queue and runs atomically
multi.exec(function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies); // 101, 2
    client.quit(); // IS THIS OPTIONAL?
});
```

I want to know if client.quit() is optional, or if multi.exec() automatically performs a quit for me? I'm trying to debug a memory leak in my redis and I realized I am not using .quit() anywhere. Should I be?

Meaning, should my code look like this?

```
client = redis.createClient();
multi = clent.multi();
multi.exec( {something} );
client.quit();
```

Basically, where does client.quit go and do I even need it?

Comment: I dont use the client.quit in my projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"MULTI commands are queued up until an EXEC is issued, and then all commands are run atomically by Redis."

This is a example from github:

```
// multi chain with an individual callback
client.multi()
    .scard("bigset")
    .smembers("bigset")
    .keys("*", function (err, replies) {
        client.mget(replies, redis.print);
    })
    .dbsize()
    .exec(function (err, replies) {
        console.log("MULTI got " + replies.length + " replies");
        replies.forEach(function (reply, index) {
            console.log("Reply " + index + ": " + reply.toString());
        });
    });
```

Your question: do i need to use `client.quit()` ? Yes, you need to because your redis connection will not be closed until you restart your redis server. You should use `client.quit()` when all your process have been completed. (In your last callback for example)

Comment: Also, a command line program that accesses redis will not complete if you don't call client.unref(), .quit(), or .end() after completion of your redis processing. Instead, the program will hang after completing, presumably waiting for the connection to redis to close.