# What is the best practice for using redis in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm building an app with nodejs, express and [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis).  I want to make a module to encapsule all the redis-related operations so that I don't have to deal with redis keys everywhere.

```
|- app.js
|- models
|   |- db.js   <-- All redis-related operations here
.....
```

Then I have two problems here.

1. I want to create the redis connection and select a database:

   ```
   var redis = require('redis');
   var client = redis.createClient();
   client.select(config.database, function() {
       // actual db code
   });
   ```

   Since `select` is an async call, how could I use it in a separate module (`db.js`)?
2. Looks like `client.quite()` must be called before the script ends, or the script won't quit.  How could I do this outside `db.js` while `client` is encapsuled as a local variable in `db.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to make something like a service/repository/interface with a defined interface, then call it's methods.

For example, if you have a users db:

```
var UserService=function(){
  this.client=new ...
}

UserService.prototype.getUserById=function(id, cb){
this.client.select(...,function(result,err){
  cb(result);
}
}

UserService.prototype.... so on
```

Now in your express app you will create an UserService var and use it.
Of course, you should create UserService smarter.
In UserService, then you can add cache.

```
var app = express();
var userService = new UserService();
//...
```

For closing read this: [Do I need to quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493196/do-i-need-to-quit-my-node-redis-client-instance-using-quit)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do think it is a good idea to put the client `select` command in each method, but doing this straightly will cause `select`command to be issued every time I call a method. Probably some wrapper that can reuse current connection would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I use this

lib/redisClient.js

```
import redis from "redis";

let _redisClient;

const redisClient = {
  createClient(uri)  {
    if (!_redisClient){
      console.log('Redis conexion created')
    _redisClient = redis.createClient(uri);
    }
    return _redisClient;
  },
  close(): void {
    _redisClient.close();
  }
};

export default redisClient;
```

index.js

```
import redisClient from "./lib/RedisClient"
...
const client = redisClient.createClient(process.env.REDISURI)
const clientA = redisClient.createClient(process.env.REDISURI)
...
```

And this only creates one connexion so you only get:

> Redis connexion created

Instead of

> Redis connexion created

> Redis connexion created